# Div collapses on ipad in safari

Tags: css, ipad, ios8, height, mobile-safari

I think it'll be best for anyone wanting to help to check my website and see the issue for him or herself. (iPad required..)

www.....net

As you see, I have 2 sections, one top section and one lower section, both have height 100%.
The lowest section has 4 div's with  different shades of blue as background-color. Now..
on the iPad (and only in safari,) I get this issue where the background-color of the lowest section div's of my website get totally messed up or collapses when I change from portrait to landscape or in reverse. 
My guess is that because safari has this new feature (as of ios 8) where when you scroll down the tabs section disappears, this in fact makes the viewport or height of the website really higher than the 100% that was previously sufficient, that is, before it disappeared, now if you make the tab come back when you're all the way down my page (by tapping it,) you'll see that this is true..

Is there some way to fix this?

If you need code here please ask but I think it'll be best for you to check it out yourself first.. because I have no idea where to start..

EDIT:
(by the way.. strange enough this does not happen on my iphone 6..)

Bowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">
    <section>
        <a href="http://www.blog.elliotwagner.net">
            <div class="bl-box">
                <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-about">Blog</h2>
            </div>
        </a>

    </section>
    <section id="bl-work-section">
        <a href="about.html">
            <div class="bl-box">
                <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-works">Résumé</h2>
            </div>
        </a>

    </section>

        <!-- For this section you need to set the top to be 50% not -50% -->



            .bl-main > section:nth-child(3) {
              top: 50%;
              left: 0;
              background: #5071B8;
            }

    <section>
        <a href="books.html">
            <div class="bl-box">
                <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-blog">Books</h2>
            </div>
        </a>


    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="about.html">
            <div class="bl-box">
                <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-contact">About</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .bl-main > section {
  height: 50vh;
}

Comment: I've fixed that, I was hacking around just now.. but still no luck. EDIT: Thanks codenine but 50vh also does not work.. the color still disappears.

Comment: All sections inside .bl-main can have equal height of 50vh.

Comment: Just apply the top: 50% on the third child and it will work on mobile 
Safari and tablets

Comment: So only 50% on the third child? Nope, still no luck, these browser issues are so annoying -.-

Comment: The only reason for the color to disappear is because the two section blocks are overlapping. This is due to the fact that the 3-rd section block is  under the 1-st

Comment: bl-main > section:nth-child(3) {
              top: 50%;
              left: 0;
              background: #5071B8;}

Comment: Also no need of  - padding: 0 5px; on <a href=""></a>

Comment: The color just disappears on the last 3 div's when rotating the ipad.

Comment: Clear cache and try with chrome debug tools. It's working fine now. I just tested it. Also enable emulate mobile

Comment: I'll try that thanks for the help, as of now I still have the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, yes in the emulator it works fine, but I need someone who owns an iPad because on my actual iPad it still displays this behavior and only there it does this.

Comment: Instead of :nth-child(4) use :nth-of-type(4) 

This will solve the problem with Safari and mobile devices